# Geometric Series Complex Exponential Form

Tags: sequences-and-series

Have I manipulated this correctly ? The sum of the roots of $z^n = - 1$ can be written as:

$$e^\frac{i3 \pi}{n}+e^\frac{i5 \pi}{n}+ \cdots +e^\frac{i(2\pi n-\pi)}{n}+e^\frac{i(2\pi n+\pi)}{n},$$

$$e^\frac{i \pi}{n} \left( e^\frac{i2 \pi}{n} + e^\frac{i4 \pi}{n} +\cdots +e^\frac{i(2\pi n-2\pi)}{n} + e^{i 2 \pi}  \right).$$

This is a geometric series with first term $a = e^\frac{i2 \pi}{n} = 0$ and common ratio $r = e^\frac{i2 \pi}{n}$. This sum is: $\frac{0(1-e^{i2 \pi})}{1-e^\frac{i 2 \pi}{n}} = 0$ as required.

**Edit - should be for numerator $a(1-1) = 0$**

Comment: I'm confused: why is $e^{i2\pi/n}=0$?

Comment: @Andrei Apologies. I was being stupid. $a = e^\frac{i 2 \pi}{n}$ but $1-r^n = 0$ clearly as $e^{i 2 \pi} = 1$

Comment: The calculation is right, **except** for the case $n=1$

Comment: @Andrei Oh yeah because then there would only be $1$ root and no complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to evaluate is put $a=\frac{i\pi}{n}$ and then evaluate $$\sum_{j=1}^ne^{(2j+1)a}=\frac{e^{3a}(e^{2an}-1)}{e^{2a}-1}$$ Now undo the substitution the numerator will become $0$

Comment: Thank you. Is my method of calculating the series correct though ?

Comment: Yeah that's correct too